# joomla using virtuemart i want the description to be placed under products

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a joomla site using virtue mart in my products. I want my description to be placed under the products. Any help would be appreciated.

You will see here that the description is above the products.

I have had a look through the source files but was wondering the best way to go about this as I may just be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using , VM2.x Versions.

The the Product Details Page Source file you can found on the following path.

```
components\com_virtuemart\views\productdetails\tmpl\
```

The `product description` and `short descriptions` are included in the `default.php` layout.
If you want to change the description ordering simply change its position as per your requirement.

`$this->product->product_s_desc` and `$this->product->product_desc;`

If you are planning to change the default VM template style , I recommend to use `Joomla Override Concept` this way you can simply override the default template with your own.

Here you need to override `productdetails` view then simply like below.

copy all the files from `components\com_virtuemart\views\productdetails\tmpl\` and paste this to , `templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/` If you unable to find this path inside your template folder you have to create that.

This will simply load your new layouts from template folder rather than default path.

Hope it clear for you..

Answer (score 0):

The VM Template system also lets you create additional view templates for categories and products. To override the default categories, category, or productdetails view, simple use the standard Joomla template override method. Copy **/components/com_virtuemart/views/[categories, category, or productdetails]/default.php** to **/templates/[Your Template]/html/com_virtuemart/[categories, category, or productdetails]/default.php** and make your changes to the template version of default.php.

To create additional views that can be set on a per category/product basis, simply copy **/templates/[Your Template]/html/[categories, category, or productdetails]/default.php** to a new file name like **/templates/[Your Template]/html/[categories, category, or productdetails]/myView.php** and make the desired changes. In the Virtuemart category or product configuration, you will find **myView** in the drop down list of alternatives views that can be used.